# Looking for a way to Query data from MySQL database & write it to a output txt file

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

Looking for a way to Query data from MySQL database & write it to a output txt file. I am trying to query a Linux server db from a remote windows box.

MySQL Query:

```
mysql -u XXX -pXXX -h ttplxapp-esm01.abc.com -D telalert -e "select max(convert_tz(start_time,\"+00:00\",\"-04:00\")) AS Time,group_concat(username SEPARATOR \" \") AS Contact, message AS Message from sends where convert_tz(start_time,\"+00:00\",\"-4:00\") like \"$query_date%\" group by alert_id order by Time desc ;"
```

A java script or script will be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Try `SELECT...FROM` statement with `INTO OUTFILE` clause.

[SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

Comment: You can run a script or a statement using [MySQL command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).